# Assiging a rank to each group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and would like to assign a rank to each row in a group. For example,

```
A,B,C,D,E
---------
1,2,5,3,5
2,4,5,4,3
1,2,3,4,5
2,4,4,5,6
3,5,6,7,7
```

So I'd like to group by columns `A` and `B` and then assign a rank based on the value of column `C` but I'd like to keep the `D` and `E` as well. If I do a group by, I have to drop the `D` and `E`. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: How do you pick a rank? Can you show a desired output?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: I'd like a similar logic to rank() function in pandas, for each group look at the value of column `C and the smallest value would be given rank 1, etc

Comment: `df.assign(rank=df.groupby(['A', 'B']).C.rank('min'))`?

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].transform(lambda x: x.rank())
```

Comment: Don't need `transform` here, just going to slow you down.

Comment: Then I'd lose the other columns (D and E) but I'd like to keep them

Comment: @user3483203 Fair enough. I was thinking that `transform` would be faster, but I just ran some timings. I don't know how much it generalizes to larger dataframes and larger number of groups, but `transform` is almost 5 times slower, which is surprising to me.

Comment: @H.Z.The columns D and E will still be in your dataframe. I'm not sure what you mean.